# How to separate packages for private use from relevant to the project in the same virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

Here's a typical workflow when working with virtual environments:

1) Create virtual envinronment:

`python3 -m venv venv`

2) Activate it:

`source venv/bin/activate`

3) Install needed requirements:

`(venv): pip install ...`

4) (Write the code of the Package)

5) Freeze the code/Create the Package dependencies.

At the last point selected python tool wraps up all the packages from my virtual environment installed at point 3).

And here's my problem. What if some requirements installed at point 3) are just private packages used only by me for development purposes? For example, in order to have Spyder editor working in different virtual environments I need to install spyder-kernels. They are not needed for my Package, and they are not needed for other developers if they don't use this editor. However, when I

`(venv): pip freeze > requirements.txt`

I get requirements.txt with spyder-kernels package included in it, and then

`(venv2): pip install -r requirements.txt`

installs all the packages from requirements.txt unless I manually delete unwanted lines.

Is there any flag for pip install that could tell pip to install some packages as hidden/private for freezing/packaging process? Or any other automatic workaround that could achieve my goal?
The perfect scenario would be something like this:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
(venv): pip install important_packages
(venv): pip install -privateFLAG spyder-kernels
(venv): pip freeze > requirements.txt  # (stores important_packages)
(venv): pip freeze -privateFLAG > private_requirements.txt
```

and then one can choose to recreate the environment depenedencies with:
'''pip install -r requirements.txt'''
or
'''pip install -r requirements.txt private_requirements.txt'''
if he needs whatever in private_requirements.txt is.

Can we do some similar trick for freezing code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such functionality in pip.

When you install a "private" package, you could add said package to a file, for example `private_requirements.txt`. Then with a simple shell script you could filter the output of `pip freeze` in a way that if a package appears in `private_requirements.txt` then the matching line should be removed from freeze output.

It should not be hard to implement, for example you could use:

```
pip freeze | grep -v -f private_requirements.txt > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Your approach does not handle the dependencies of the private_package. However I think I found a way to improve it. With the use of `pip-autoremove` I could list unused dependencies for the packages gathered in private_requirements.txt (-l option), and then having this list in private_requirements_and_their_unused_deps.txt I could go on with your filtering. 

I've just checked that pyinstaller does the job automatically.

Comment: Nice, sorry I didn't think about the dependencies... However I'll just add that I always prefer a clean requirements list, by manually listing the packages I actually use, not listing dependencies at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with one of the following tools, see if it fits your needs:

- [`pipdeptree --freeze --packages MyProject > requirements.txt`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/)
- [`pipreqs .`](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/)
- [`deptree MyProject > requirements.txt`](https://pypi.org/project/deptree/) (Disclaimer: my code)

These should fill the `requirements.txt` with only the dependencies for that one project.

Comment: I admit I gave a very brief glance at the links you provided (so correct me if I'm wrong), but I don't see any straightforward use of the tools you proposed for my particular problem. Those tools can be used only to simplify the approach proposed by rolf82 by generating dependencies lists of all the packages.

Comment: Well `pip freeze` lists everything in the environment. With _pipdeptree_ and_deptree_ you can somewhat filter that list by giving the name of one (or more) projects as input and getting the list of the dependencies only for these projects. So for example, in your case, I believe `spyder-kernels` would be left out, since it is not a (direct or indirect) dependency of your actual project.

Comment: @equator You could also look into [_pip-tools_](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/), and maintain one or multiple `requirements.in`.